# Color d3 radial tree according to node property

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Similarly to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46438394/how-do-you-specify-node-colors-for-the-d3-radial-tree) I would like to build a colored radial tree with d3.js, starting from the example in [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550). I am a complete newbie in both javascript and d3.

I'd like to make it so that the nodes - and/or the terminal part of the edges - are colored with different intensity according to some property encoded in the original csv. Example would be:

```
id,value
flare,
flare.analytics,
flare.analytics.cluster,
flare.analytics.cluster.AgglomerativeCluster,3938
flare.analytics.cluster.CommunityStructure,3812
flare.analytics.cluster.HierarchicalCluster,6714
flare.analytics.cluster.MergeEdge,743
```

where I would like to color nodes depending on "value"
This does not work:

```
node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 2.5)
      .style('fill', function(d) {
        if (Number(d.value) > Number(4000)){
          return "orange";
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `d.data.value` instead of `d.value`